# jquery find attribute id

Tags: jquery

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
var parent = '';
$('a.tip').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
parent = $(this).parent();
$('#deletelink').dialog('open');
return false;
});
$('#deletelink').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
width: 300,
buttons: {
"Ok": function() {
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'asd',
data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
beforeSend: function() {
parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
},
success: function() {
parent.slideUp(300,function() {
parent.remove();
});
}
});
$(this).dialog("close");
},
"Cancel": function() {
$(this).dialog("close");
}
}
});
});
```

Which I use with the following html code:

```
    <li class="odd">
    <div class="avatar-container">
        <div class="avatar">
            <div class="imgDelete" id="record-1" style="text-align:center;">
                <a class="tip" href="javascript:void(0);" title="This action cannot be undone!"><span>Delete</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </li>
<li class="even">
    <div class="avatar-container">
        <div class="avatar">
            <div class="imgDelete" id="record-2" style="text-align:center;">
                <a class="tip" href="javascript:void(0);" title="This action cannot be undone!"><span>Delete</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </li>
```

The html code above is generated with php loop.

My problem is that when i click on "Delete" link, only parent div is slided up. I need to make it to slide up the whole `<li>`.
Any help?

Comment: Can you format that JS please? :/

Comment: If your TAB is broken, you can use jsbeautifier.com or a similar service

Answer (score 1):

```
parent = $(this).parent();
```

refers to the parent DIV not the LI, you need to use chained parents, ie. .parent().parent() but use however many it takes to get back up to the LI elements

Comment: `closest` is definitely the solution here. Chained `parent()` calls make your code very inflexible should you modify your HTML.

Comment: talk about ugly code `.parent().parent().parent().parent()`  eek.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are selecting the immediate `.parent()` of the link which is the `<div class="imgDelete"..` element

You need to use

```
parent = $(this).closest('li');
```

instead of

```
parent = $(this).parent();
```

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches **up** the dom hierarchy to find the next element that matches the selector.  In your case the selector is `'li'`, so it will search up the DOM hierarchy to find a `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest('li');
```

This will give you the `li` ancestor, the clicked element is contained in.